# how to get back to the previous array value by using the button

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

how can I return to the previous array value?

hey, i'm new here and i'm still just learning about android and java, can you help me? how can I return to the previous array value?
thank you

```
    btnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambar);
    btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback);


    btnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if (gambar == 11) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(penggunaanturunan.this, pembukaanstastioner.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {

                    gambar=gambar & aturan.length;
                    gambar++;

                    imageView.setImageResource(aturan[gambar]);
                }
        }
    });

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            gambar = (gambar + aturan.length) & aturan.length;
            gambar--;
            imageView.setImageResource(aturan[gambar]);
        }
    });
```

I tried the code in btnback, it can return to the previous array value but it doesn't return in sequence but instead is random, I want to be able to return to the previous array value in sequence

Comment: sorry, the array is left behind, this is the array
 private int aturan [] = {R.drawable.bgpenggunaan1, R.drawable.bgpenggunaan2, R.drawable.bgpenggunaan3, R.drawable.bgpenggunaan4, R.drawable.bgpenggunaan5,
    R.drawable.bgfungsinaik2, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik2, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik3, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik4, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik5, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik6, R.drawable.bgfungsinaik7};

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand it right, you need move index in the array to previous value.
Just make it -1 like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (gambar > 0) {
        gambar--;
        imageView.setImageResource(aturan[gambar]);
    }
}
```